# Python Requests post XML file not working

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

I'm trying to debug why i'm not able to POST an xml file with requests `.post()` to an API. The following `wget` command works fine:

```
wget -vv --no-check-certificate --post-file dynobjadd.xml \ 
"https://1.1.1.1/api/?type=user-id&action=set&key=$MYSUPERSECRETKEY=&file-name=dynobjadd.xml&client=wget" \ 
--no-http-keep-alive -O response.out
```

successful wget output:

```
... 
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
--2017-01-05 13:21:11--  https://1.1.1.1/api/?type=user-id&action=set&key=$MYSUPERSECRETKEY=&file-name=dynobjadd.xml&client=wget
Certificates loaded: 165
Connecting to 1.1.1.1:443... connected.
...
---request begin---
POST https://1.1.1.1/api/?type=user-id&action=set&key=$MYSUPERSECRETKEY=&file-name=dynobjadd.xml&client=wget  HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.18 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: 1.1.1.1
Connection: Close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 175

---request end---
[writing BODY file dynobjadd.xml ... done]
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: 
Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2017 20:21:12 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 255
Connection: close
ETag: "437cf-12b-56e39c36"
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=123123; path=/; secure; HttpOnly

---response end---
200 OK
```

python code i am trying:

```
xml = open('dynobjadd.xml').read()



url = 'https://1.1.1.1/api/?type=user-id&action=set&key=$MYSUPERSECRETKEY=&file-name=dynobjadd.xml&client=requests'
r = requests.post(url, data=xml, verify=False  )
```

`r.content()` output:

```
<response status = 'error' code = '400'><result><msg>No file uploaded</msg></result></response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use argument 'files'.
From http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file :

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
>>> r.text
{
    ...
    "files": {
         "file": "<censored...binary...data>"
    },
    ...
}
```